# analytification of a projective algebraic variety

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

When we "analytify" an algebraic subvariety X of projective space $\mathbb{P}_r(\mathbb{C})$ in GAGA, https://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/courses/256A/, are we simply putting the usual topology on it along with the induced sheaf of holomorphic functions?
see also: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-726-algebraic-geometry-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_726s09_lec22_gaga.pdf

I'm a bit confused as to what the open sets in analytified X look like. Is the topology the subspace topology? Do we need to use the standard cover $D(x_i)$ of $\mathbb{P}_r(\mathbb{C})$ to define an analytic space? are $D(x_i)$ open sets in the usual topology?

Comment: Yes on all counts.

Comment: Can you explain the "adjunction" defined by Kedlaya?